# "no dataset available", when running script

Tags: bash, backup, zfs, snapshot

I'm new to zfs and I started making a script to build on to eventually (hopefully) become an automatic backup script for my server.

But when I try to run my script, it echoes "no datasets available".

I don't think its the code but rather something I'm missing..

`#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $echo $@

### On the first day of every week (Sunday), takes a snapshot of all ZFS

### filesystems. These are exported as incremental snapshots, based off the

### previous monthly or weekly snapshot (whichever was done last). Any

### existing daily snapshots are deleted.

## #

### On the subsequent days of every week (M-Sat), takes a snapshot of all

### ZFS filesystems. These are exported as incremental snapshots, based off

### the previous monthly, weekly, or daily snapshot (whichever was done

### last).

## #

## #

#### USER-EDITABLE VARIABLES

## The root ZFS pool to back up

zfs_root_pool="rpool"

## The prefix to use for ZFS snapshots created by this script

zfsdr_snap_prefix="zfs-dr"

## The directory where the completed archives should be stored

main_backup_dir="/backup"

## If false, the script will exit immediately after taking snapshots if the

## main backup directory is unavailable. If true, the script will export the

## snapshots and do any configured compression / encryption, but will not move the

## finished archive file to the main storage.

continue_without_main_backup_dir="false"

## The directory where temporary files should be stored

main_temp_dir="/backup"

## Should exported archives be compressed?

compress_backup="true"

## Should exported archives be encrypted?

encrypt_backup="true"

## Should intermediate steps be deleted immediately after use (could be

## useful if the main temp directory is on a space-constrained filesystem)

delete_intermediate_steps_immediately="false"

## Allow this script to automatically delete old archive files from

## previous backup cycles?

auto_delete_old_archives="true"

#### FUNCTIONS

do_daily_snap() {
  /sbin/zfs list -t snapshot -o name | grep ^"$zfs_root_pool"@"$zfsdr_snap_prefix"_monthly$
  if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
    return
  fi

get_current_week

# If we haven't had a weekly snapshot yet, than don't look for one.
  if [[ $current_week -gt 0 ]]; then
    /sbin/zfs list -t snapshot -o name | grep ^"$zfs_root_pool"@"$zfsdr_snap_prefix"_weekly"$current_week"$
    if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
      throw_warning "Missing weekly snapshot detected; performing weekly snapshot instead."
      do_weekly_snap
      return
    fi
  fi

current_dow=`date +%w`

/sbin/zfs snapshot -r "$zfs_root_pool"@"$zfsdr_snap_prefix"_daily"$current_dow"

if [[ ! -d $main_backup_dir && "$continue_without_main_backup_dir" != "true" ]]; then
    throw_error "Snapshot created, exiting because $main_backup_dir is not available..."
  fi

previous_dow=$(( $current_dow - 1 ))
  previous_day=$(( `date +%e` - 1 ))

# If the previous dow was zero or the previous day was one, then we don't expect to find any previous
  # daily snapshots.
  # Check the previous days until we find one that exists, or we run out of days to check.
  # Note that dow can reach one (we've reached the first possible daily snapshot in the week) OR day
  # can reach two (we've reached the first possible daily backup in the month), and either condition
  # should stop the check.
    # If previous day of week is greater than zero (and we didn't reach the beginning of the month),
    # export based on the previous daily.
    # If previous day of week reached zero and current week is greater than zero, export based on the
    # current weekly snapshot. (If we reached the beginning of the month before reaching the beginning
    # of the week, we're automatically in week zero.)
    # If we're in week zero, export based on the monthly snapshot.
}

get_current_week() {
  eval start_of_week=$(( `date +%e` - `date +%w` ))
  if [[ $start_of_week -le 1 ]]; then
    current_week=0
  elif [[ $start_of_week -ge 2 && $start_of_week -le 8 ]]; then
    current_week=1
  elif [[ $start_of_week -ge 9 && $start_of_week -le 15 ]]; then
    current_week=2
  elif [[ $start_of_week -ge 16 && $start_of_week -le 22 ]]; then
    current_week=3
  elif [[ $start_of_week -ge 23 && $start_of_week -le 29 ]]; then
    current_week=4
  else
    current_week=5
  fi

previous_week=$(( $current_week - 1 ))
}

#### MAIN SCRIPT

if [[ `date +%e` -eq 1 ]]; then
  do_monthly_snap
elif [[ `date +%w` -eq 0 ]]; then
  do_weekly_snap
else
  do_daily_snap
fi`

I am breaking up a prebuilt script and slowly making it the way i need it 
[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlIwL.png)
    [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kHxd.png)
[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsKnf.png)
  [The code im using as model](https://github.com/txr13/zfs-dr/blob/master/zfs-dr.sh)

Comment: Where are you defining `$zfs_root_pool` and `$zfsdr_snap_prefix`? Are they set when you run the commands? As always, the first step in debugging is "print all the things". So, modify your script so that it prints out the commands it is running to see what you are actually executing.

Comment: zfs_root_pool="rpool"

zfsdr_snap_prefix="zfs-dr"  Thanks! I will start using print now.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us where those variables are set in your script and how you execute the script. Ideally, also include the _full_ script, is there a `#!/bin/bash` line? Perhaps something else? I am reasonably certain they are not set when the commands are run, but since you don't show your whole script and don't show how you execute the scripts, I have no way of knowing for sure.

Comment: Thanks again for giving some of your time

Comment: But, you removed even the little code you were showing before! We can't help you debug code you don't show us. So I ask again, please [EDIT] your question and show us the script you are running. You probably have a syntax error, looks like you're missing a space before the `]]`, but it's kind of hard to tell without seeing the code. And the error you mention ("no datasets available") is completely different to the one you show later. And what are these two  `rpool/backup` and `rpool/root` things? How are they relevant? Please clarify what you are doing and what is going wrong.